# How to transfer mail/contacts from Outlook 2011 for the Mac to Outlook 2010 for Windows

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, microsoft-outlook-2011

I'm moving from OSX/Outlook 2011 to Windows 7/Outlook 2010.

How do I transfer my mail items/ folders/ contacts? The mail is fetched via a POP3 server and stored locally on the Mac.

I've found this answer on the official support forums and it suggests that this is not possible: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mac/forum/macoffice2011-macoutlook/outlook-2011-data-files-to-pst/17906b6f-f276-4da7-b8e0-820699aca518

That sounds (to put it politely) TOTALLY INSANE. And I'm thinking there must be a work around.

Has anyone worked out a way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now, you'll need to use a 3rd party software or service to convert it between programs.

I'd say check out [Emailchemy](http://www.weirdkid.com/products/emailchemy/):

> Emailchemy can read:
>
> - AOL for Windows ("PFC" files)
> - Apple Mail
> - Claris Emailer for Macintosh
> - CompuServe Classic for Macintosh (MacCIM)
> - CompuServe for Windows (WinCIM and 2000)
> - Entourage (Database, .RGE Archives and cache files)
> - Eudora
> - Mozilla
> - Mulberry
> - Musashi
> - Neoplanet
> - Netscape
> - Opera
> - **Outlook for Mac (8.x, 2001, and 2011 OLM files)**
> - Outlook for Windows (MSG, PST and OST files)
> - Outlook Express for Macintosh
> - Outlook Express for Windows
> - Outlook Express for UNIX/Solaris
> - Outspring
> - PowerTalk/AOCE for Macintosh
> - QuickMail Pro for Macintosh
> - QuickMail Pro for Windows
> - Thunderbird
> - Windows Live Mail
> - Windows Mail
> - Yahoo! Mail
> - any UNIX-style or mbox-format mailbox
>
> Emailchemy can write:
>
> - Apple Mail .mbox folders
> - Entourage Archives (.rge files)
> - Thunderbird folders
> - MBOX files (RFC-2822 mailboxes)
> - EML files (folders of .eml RFC-2822 message files)
> - CSV files (comma-separated value files)
> - IMAPdir (Binc IMAP maildir)
> - Maildir++ (Courier IMAP maildir)
> - IMAP email account and folders usable by Outlook
>
> Emailchemy can also:
>
> - Import email into Outlook and any other IMAP-compatible email application
> - Upload email into Google Apps

Comment: That worked but was suprisingly difficult. This tutorial definitely helped, I wish I'd found it a few hours back: http://www.weirdkid.com/blog/2009/02/08/video-walkthrough-for-importing-email-into-outlook/